# tk.mainloop() vs root.mainloop()?

Tags: python, tkinter, mainloop

I have tried to find some Q/A or article about the use of `tk.mainloop()` vs `root.mainloop()` with no success.

My question is this: Is there any difference between the 2 uses. It seams to me the correct method would be to use `tk_instance_variable_name.mainloop()` vs just doing `tk.mainloop()` but from what I can see both appear to work just fine. Is there any reason one would need to avoid `tk.mainloop()` or is it just a preference.

If this has been asked before please provide the Q/A link as I cannot seam to find it. I feel like it would have been asked already but no luck search for it.

Can someone maybe explain why `tk.mainloop()` will work here when I feel like it should not work as it is not being used on the tk instance variable name.

Example using `root` work just as expected:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="Test").pack()
root.mainloop() # using the variable name root
```

Example using `tk` works fine as well as far as I can tell:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="Test").pack()
tk.mainloop() # using tk
```

Comment: No, there's no difference. `tk.mainloop()` is a helper function that looks up the root instance and calls `root.mainloop()`. [See it here.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L555).

Comment: @Novel I see you linked to what looks like source code but I still don't understand how `tk.mainloop()` knows to loop on `root` when its not being told to. Also wouldn't this be a problem for multiple instances of tk. There are some case uses for having more than one instance of tk up so would `tk.mainloop()` fail in this case?

Comment: When you create a `Tk()` instance, the global variable `tkinter._default_root` is set if it isn't already. Therefore _default_root
 is the first instance of `Tk()` created. [Code here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2055). If you have multiple instances of `Tk()` (which you shouldn't) then `tkinter.mainloop()` is an alias to the `mainloop()` method of the first `Tk()` instance you created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have tried to find some Q/A or article about the use of tk.mainloop() vs root.mainloop() with no success.
>
> My question is this: Is there any difference between the 2 uses.

Short answer: there is no difference in the normal use case.

Every widget has an associated tcl interpreter that is created when a root widget is created, whether either explicitly or implicitly. When you call `mainloop` from any widget, it will run the `mainloop` function in the interpreter associated with the root window of that widget.

If you call the `mainloop` method that is part of the `tkinter` module (eg: `tk.mainloop()` in your example), it will call the `mainloop` function of the default interpreter. The default interpreter is the first interpreter that was created. Thus, in the normal case of a single instance of `Tk`, `tk.mainloop()` and `root.mainloop()` call the exact same code.

Comment: OP is asking about the `tkinter.mainloop()` function; not a widget method.

Comment: I realize having 2 active instance if TK is unlikely. I just wanted to cover all the options. I guess I am still trying to rap my head around it. So from what you have said and what @Novel has said let me see if I get this. So no mater how I call `mainloop()` (via variable name or directly against the tk import) then the mainloop() functions should look up the default instance and loop on that.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: No. If called on a widget, it will call the mainloop function for the interpreter associated with that widget. If you call the module-level one, it will call it on the first interpreter that was created. I'll try to clarify my answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley the big difference is that `tkinter.mainloop()` has no way to know which `Tk()` instance / tcl interpreter to use, so it uses the first one created.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I think I see whats going on here. I didn't realize `mainloop()` was coded in such a way to work on the default interpreter. My original understanding was that `mainloop()` needed to be used on the instance of tk directly to work. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, every tkinter widget inherits that method, so this works too:

```
import tkinter as tk

lbl = tk.Label(text="Test")
lbl.pack()
lbl.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Novel, My confusion has been cleared up between you and Bryan.